# Best practice for real-world DAOs using @Cacheable annotations

Tags: java, spring, caching, annotations, ehcache

I'm new to Spring and I'm very excited about all the things it offers!

Right now, I'm trying to modernize a couple of DAOs in my existing project.
Specifically, I want to replace my old plain JDBC code with Spring Jdbc support and introduce Spring's transparent caching.

1. First question: am I right that the DAO layer is the right place to add `@Cacheable` annotations? Or do you do it in the business layer?
2. I can follow all the simple examples to be found on the net. However, when it comes to more *real world* code, I get stuck:

Specifically, I have several methods that return instances of my model `Publisher`. In my manual cache implementations I always made sure only one instance is cached and fetched for the different `getPublisher()` methods. However, using `@Cacheable` and trying to encapsulate caching within the DAO, I have the problem, that the annotation doesn't work for local method calls (because of proxying).

Here's my sample code:

```
@Cacheable("publisherCache")
public Publisher getPublisher(int publisherId)
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM publisher LEFT JOIN publisherContacts USING (publisherId) WHERE publisherId=? ORDER BY publisherContactId ASC";
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, publisherResultSetExtractor, publisherId);
}

public List<Publisher> findVisiblePublishers()
{
    List<Publisher> publishers = new LinkedList<Publisher>();
    for (int publisherId : findVisiblePublisherIds())
    {
        publishers.add(getPublisher(publisherId));
    }
    return publishers;
}

@Cacheable(value = "publisherCache", key = "'list'")
private List<Integer> findVisiblePublisherIds()
{
    String sql = "SELECT publisherId FROM publisher WHERE isVisible='yes' ORDER BY imprintName";
    return getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql, Integer.class);
}

public Publisher findNearestPublisher(String appx)
{
    appx = "%" + appx + "%";
    String sql = "SELECT publisherId FROM publisher WHERE publisherName LIKE ? OR imprintName LIKE ? ORDER BY imprintName DESC LIMIT 1";
    Integer publisherId = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Integer.class, appx, appx);
    if (publisherId == null)
        return null;
    else
        return getPublisher(publisherId);
}
```

This was my idea, which as said, doesn't work.

The only alternatives I can see right now are:

a) Only cache the `getPublisher(publisherId)` method and define all other methods that return `Publisher`s to return `int`s (publisherIds), or lists thereof. This doesn't feel natural from an API point of view. As a service or business logic, I would expect to get instances from the DAO, not only IDs.

b) Add `@Cacheable` to all methods, duplicating the cache and using more memory than needed (let's assume there are a lot of publishers and that they are heavy objects).

What is the best practice around this *must-be-pretty-common* problem?
Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Better to put two question in two SO questions.

Comment: Why don't cache the result of `findVisiblePublishers` method? Yes, it will run two DB queries when invoked for the first time, but that's it. I think it's a good target for caching

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Because it will cache the Publisher objects for every list of Publishers that I return (and cache). The approach shown above using getPublisher(id) doesn't work. When you call getPublisher(id) from the same class, the cache is not asked, but a DB request is performed every time. That means that I have two instances of the same Publisher cached, once in the list, and once as a single item. When I have more similar methods, things will get worse.

Answer (score 0):

Common pattern is following:
For persistence layer you use hibernate second-level cache.
For service layer you use @Cacheable to cache things like long computations or web service call results.

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for your answer. This answers part of my my first question. So, I'm doing it right, when doing it in the DAO layer when my purpose is to save DB requests (I can't use Hibernate/JPA). Anyways, even in the service layer, I'd have the same problem for question 2. Moving the @Cacheable to service level doesn't solve my problem with duplicate caching.